# drag and drop event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

**Currently i am having problem with drag and drop event in fullcalendar: i don't know how to handle it!**

**Description the problem:**

- I want only the blue line to be dragged and dropped, and the remaining lines are not dragged (because the blue part is the admin's part to confirm the division of work, and the rest is for the user):
  [my calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzqIZ.png)
- after drag and drop it will look like this:

> Before [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8cVs.png)

> Expected: [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNjmV.png)

- I want after onclick column will start dragging the blue line from the click position

**Here is my code:**

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
    var events = [];

    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
        initialView: "resourceTimelineDay",
        headerToolbar: {
            left: "",
            center: "title",
            right: "prev,next today",
        },
        height: "auto",
        locale: "ja",
        editable: true,
        resourceAreaColumns: [{
                field: 'title',
                headerContent: 'スタッフ'
            },
            {
                field: 'count',
                headerContent: '出勤回数'
            }
        ],
        resourceAreaWidth: "190px",
        views: {
            resourceTimelineDay: {
                slotDuration: "00:15:00",
                slotMinWidth: "10",
            },
        },
        eventDidMount: function(view, element) {
            var currentdate = view.intervalStart;
            $('.datetime-picker').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date(currentdate));
        },
        resources: [{
                id: "1",
                title: "佐藤",
                count: "10",
                eventColor: "#b6d7a8"
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                title: "山田",
                count: "12",
                eventColor: "#ffe5e5"
            },
            {
                id: "3",
                title: "田中",
                count: "3",
                eventColor: "#bbd6ee"
            },
            {
                id: "4",
                title: "鈴木",
                count: "5",
                eventColor: "#e7e6e6"
            },
        ],
        // リソースごとのイベントを定義
        events: [{
                resourceId: "1",
                title: "",
                start: "2022-08-10T09:00:00",
                end: "2022-08-10T15:00:00",
            },
            {
                resourceId: "2",
                title: "",
                start: "2022-08-10T00:00:00",
                end: "2022-08-10T24:00:00",
            },
            {
                resourceId: "3",
                title: "",
                start: "2022-08-10T00:00:00",
                end: "2022-08-10T24:00:00",
            },
            {
                resourceId: "4",
                title: "",
                start: "2022-08-10T00:00:00",
                end: "2022-08-10T24:00:00",
            },
        ],
    });
    calendar.render();
```

```html
<div id="calendar" class="w-full"></div>
```

**Thanks all !**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that you only want it to be possible to move certain  events, and not be allowed to move others?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, exactly i just want to move the blue part and the rest of the colors are not moved

Comment: OK. You can set the "editable" property om each event to determine whether an event is allowed to be moved or not.